# How to display my database data on HTML web-site SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I am creating a simple web site for job listing. I have created 3 tables on Server that I will use for the purpose of saving data.

1. dbo.jobs - job_id (pk, int, (1,1)), job_title, job_text, job_type_id, place_id
2. dbo.job_types - job_type_id (pk, int, (1,1)), job_type_name
3. dbo.places - place_id (pk, int, (1,1)), place_name

I created one .php file for connection, and other .php code is inline in HTML.
connect-mysql.php (Windows autentification):

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS01"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Studentski_posao");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?> 

<?php
include ('connect-mysql.php');
$sqlget = "Select * from dbo.places";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlget) or die ("greška prilikom dohvatanja podataka"); 

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>place_id</th><th>place_name</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata), MYSQL_ASSOC){
    echo"<tr><td>";
    echo $row[place_id']; 
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['place_name']; 
    echo "</td> </tr>"
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

The final result looks like:
Half of the .php code is printed out
[image: Half of the .php code is printed out]

This was just a test to show a data from one table, but the final idea of the project is that user can choose job_type_name and place_name and get the jobs that matches criteria.

I am stuck on this for more that 14 days and only help I found was for mySQL witch didn't find helping.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo: `echo $row[place_id'];` should be `echo $row['place_id'];` (you missed the opening `'`)

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing `sqlsrv_*` with `mysqli_*`. Those are two totally different API's, targeting two totally different databases and can't be mixed like that. Also, `mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata), MYSQL_ASSOC` has two issues. The first is that `MYSQL_ASSOC`  is for the `mysql_*`-api, not the `mysqli_*`-api. Also, the constant should be the second argument to `mysqli_fetch_array()`. You've put it _after_ the method, making it the second argument to your `while()` command instead.

Comment: There are too many issues here. You should start over from the beginning. Do one thing at the time and make that work before adding more features. You should also read the manual about how to use the different functions.